# Run-time error '13' Type mismatch: If Or

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I'm new to stackoverflow and have been finding it incredibly useful.  Hope somebody will answer my query below.

```
Currency1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup("Currency", _ 
Worksheets("abc").Range("T5:Z6"), 2, False)
...
Currency1 = "USD" Or "CNY" Or "GBP" Or "AUD" Or "NZD" Then
```

Type mismatch error pops up.
It works fine before the "Or ..." statement is added.

I tried with permutations of the following lines but they doesn't solve the problem.

```
Dim Currency1 As String

If Currency1 = ("USD" Or "CNY" Or "GBP" Or "AUD" Or "NZD") Then
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can not do an `Or` on string values, i.e. `"USD" Or "CNY"` is not a sensible calculation.  You want `If Currency = "USD" Or Currency = "CNY" Or ... Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply this?
Declare a string variable to hold all the currencies and use Instr function to check if the Currency1 variable is valid.

```
Dim Currency1 As String
Dim strCurr As String
strCurr = "USD,CNY,GBP,AUD,NZD"
Currency1 = "GBP"
If InStr(strCurr, Currency1) > 0 Then
    'Do your stuff here if the Currencey1 is a valid currency
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Currency1 = "USD" Or Currency1 = "CNY" Or Currency1 = "GBP" Or Currency1 = "AUD" Or Currency1 = "NZD" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, except `If Currency1 = "USD" Or Currency1 = "CNY"`, as already proposed in the comments. It is a bit more complicated, it uses an additional function, checking whether the value is in an array.

Thus, in this case we may pass the array as string `"USD:AUD:DEM"` or as a real array `Array("USD", "AUD", "DEM")`, depending on our needs. In the example below I have showed both options.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function b_value_in_array(my_value As Variant, my_array As Variant, Optional b_is_string As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim l_counter

    If b_is_string Then
        my_array = Split(my_array, ":")
    End If

    For l_counter = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)
        my_array(l_counter) = CStr(my_array(l_counter))
    Next l_counter

    b_value_in_array = Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(my_value), my_array, 0))

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim Currency1 As String

    Currency1 = "USD"

    If b_value_in_array(Currency1, Array("USD", "AUD", "DEM")) Then
        Debug.Print "Value is in the array."
    End If

    If b_value_in_array(Currency1, "USD:AUD:DEM", True) Then
        Debug.Print "Value is in the array."
    End If

End Sub
```